# How do I get the oldest point in a VictoriaMetrics time series?

Tags: victoriametrics

What is the equivalent of this InfluxDB query in VictoriaMetrics?

```
SELECT * FROM ${measurement}
    WHERE ...
    LIMIT 1
```

[VictoriaMetrics doesn't have a LIMIT modifier](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/2467), so a query like
`${metric}{...labels...}[20y]`
will return ALL points. (Also, `20y` is dicey, but [an arbitrarily large duration won't work](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/5553).)

I only need the timestamp of that point.

Answer (score 0):

One answer is [`tfirst_over_time`](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#tfirst_over_time):

> returns the timestamp in seconds for the first raw sample on the given lookbehind window `d` per each time series returned from the given series_selector.

So,

```
tfirst_over_time(${metric}{...labels...}[100y])
```

You still have to supply an arbitrarily large duration, but surprisingly, `100y` doesn't seem to [bug](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/5553) `tfirst_over_time`.